# Selenium with .net core: performance impact, multiple threads in IWebElement?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using Selenium for writing an end to end tests using the .net framework 4.6.
For a new project I'm using Selenium to do some web crawling but I'm experiencing enormous lag on very simple Selenium tasks.
Please look at the screenshot below:

[image]

The code itself is here:

```
public IList<Category> ListAllParentCategories()
{
    var categories = new List<Category>();
    var liItems = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".nav__branch.branch ul.tree li"));
    foreach(var liItem in liItems)
    {
        var innerLink = liItem.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));

        var c = new Category();
        c.Id = long.Parse(liItem.GetAttribute("id"));
        c.Link = innerLink.GetAttribute("href");
        c.Name = innerLink.Text;
        c.Parent = null;

        categories.Add(c);
    }
    return categories;
}
```

From my experience, this should not take minutes to complete. Basically, we're just looking for a list of LI elements and then we query for some more info related to that element, which does not require interaction from the browser as it's already contained in the WebElement.

Yet this procedure (for 22 categories) takes at least an entire minute. Fetching the `innerlink.GetAttribute("id")` takes an entire second.

Now while trying to figure out why this is happening, I've been removing all thread related stuff and right now this code runs from a Console app. There's no improvement at all.

A curious thing is that when I open the `innerLink` in the debugger, I can see that most properties are using another thread?! I assume this is what is causing the long delays?

My setup is as follows:
- Console app running .NET Core 2.0
Dependencies:
- Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver 2.32.00
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.6.0

**Update:** This problem is definitely related to the .NET core variant of Selenium Webdriver. After converting the project to a regular .NET Framework 4.6 Console app, everything is 10 times faster.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and how multi-threading is related since you don't see any improvement in a single threaded console application. Be aware that parallel execution is not possible on a single session of the browser.

Comment: I just find Selenium to be terribly slow compared to using it with .Net framework 4.6. I want to know what might be causing this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please advice if you find a solution! :)

Comment: @noobed haven't found one, just reverted back to old school .net framework :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dirty fix for the problem for now.

```
//this is in my Dependency Register method
string driverPath = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}";
var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
container.RegisterInstance<IWebDriver>(new FirefoxDriver(service), new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
FixDriverCommandExecutionDelay(container.Resolve<IWebDriver>());
```

and the method looks something like this:

```
//to be deleted when https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24104 is fixed
//in .net core 2.0
public static void FixDriverCommandExecutionDelay(IWebDriver driver)
{
    PropertyInfo commandExecutorProperty = typeof(RemoteWebDriver).GetProperty("CommandExecutor", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    ICommandExecutor commandExecutor = (ICommandExecutor)commandExecutorProperty.GetValue(driver);

    FieldInfo remoteServerUriField = commandExecutor.GetType().GetField("remoteServerUri", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField);

     if (remoteServerUriField == null)
     {
         FieldInfo internalExecutorField = commandExecutor.GetType().GetField("internalExecutor", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField);
         commandExecutor = (ICommandExecutor)internalExecutorField.GetValue(commandExecutor);
         remoteServerUriField = commandExecutor.GetType().GetField("remoteServerUri", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField);
            }

    if (remoteServerUriField != null)
    {
        string remoteServerUri = remoteServerUriField.GetValue(commandExecutor).ToString();

         string localhostUriPrefix = "http://localhost";

         if (remoteServerUri.StartsWith(localhostUriPrefix))
         {
             remoteServerUri = remoteServerUri.Replace(localhostUriPrefix, "http://127.0.0.1");

             remoteServerUriField.SetValue(commandExecutor, new Uri(remoteServerUri));
          }
  }
```

the answer to the problem is explained fully in this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24104
Answer taken from there also, credits given to the good folks!

It works for me on FF driver v0.19.1, Selenium v3.8

Comment: Thanks for posting back here, after you've found the solution. I've just tried this for a new project using the ChromDriver and it works perfect!